# unable to start rails server without normalize-scss gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After commenting out normalize-scss in my Gemfile and running rails -s, I get:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/ItsMe/foo/bar/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
```

Adding the gem back in lets me run the server.

...why? I've already checked bin/rails:6, and APP_PATH looks totally fine.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.5'
# gem 'normalize-scss', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.5.1'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'susy', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.6'
gem 'breakpoint', '~> 2.5'



# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
    gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
```

Comment: did you run bundle install after commenting out the gem?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first step.

Comment: what does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: Gemfile added to question body.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had required the gem in config/application.rb. Removed it, and solved.